# Joomla 2.5 displaying data /multiple rows in view

Tags: view, joomla, components

I'm new to joomla development. After having managed to directly list database multiple rows directly into the conttroller, i'm trying to display it using views, but i have an error message :

**Controller :**

```
function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
{
     // Affichage de la liste des tournois

     $db=JFactory::getDBO();
     $sql="select * from #__tournois_tournois";
     //echo $sql;
     $db->setQuery($sql);
     $db->query();
     $items=$db->loadobjectList();       

     // set default view if not set
     $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
     $input->set('view', $input->getCmd('view', 'Tournois'));

     // call parent behavior
     parent::display($cachable);
```

**in my view :**

```
function display($tpl = null) 
{
     // Get data from the model
     $items = $this->get('Items');

     // Check for errors.
     if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) 
     {
             JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
             return false;
     }
     // Assign data to the view
     $this->items = $items;

     // Set the toolbar
     $this->addToolBar();

     // Display the template
     parent::display($tpl);
}
```

**In the default tpl :**

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_tournoi&ask=edit'); ?>" method="post" name="adminTournoisForm" id="adminTournoisForm">
<table class='adminlist'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th width='1%'>&nbsp;</th>
<th class='title'>ID</th>
<th class='title'>Tournoi</th>
<?
foreach ($this->items as $i => $item)
{
    //$row=$rows[$i]?>
    <tr>
     <th><? echo $item->tournois_id?></th>
    <th><? echo $item->tournois_title?></th>
    </tr>
<?}?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You should be doing your query in the model and also using JDatabaseQuery. Also I assume you mean task not ask.